# When remapping hyper key/caps lock to F18 with Hammerspoon, is it possible to use it with modifiers

Tags: hammerspoon

My issue is as follows: I have my caps lock remapped to F18 using Karabiner Elements, and then Hammerspoon uses F18 as a "hyper key" to perform app specific shortcuts.

My current code looks like this:

```lua
-- A global variable for the Hyper Mode
k = hs.hotkey.modal.new({}, "F17")

launch = function(bundleID)
  hs.application.launchOrFocusByBundleID(bundleID)
  k.triggered = true
end

-- Single keybinding for app launch
singleapps = {
  {'f', 'com.apple.Finder'},
  {'c', 'com.google.Chrome'},
}

for i, app in ipairs(singleapps) do
  k:bind({}, app[1], function() launch(app[2]); end, nil, function() launch(app[2]); end)
```

I also have HJKJ mapped to arrow keys when using the hyper key to have vim like navigation everywhere:

```lua
arrowKey = function(arrow, modifiers) 
  local event = require("hs.eventtap").event
  event.newKeyEvent(modifiers, string.lower(arrow), true):post()
  event.newKeyEvent(modifiers, string.lower(arrow), false):post()
end

k:bind({}, 'h', function() arrowKey('LEFT', {}); end, nil, function() arrowKey('LEFT', {}); end)
k:bind({}, 'j', function() arrowKey('DOWN', {}); end, nil, function() arrowKey('DOWN', {}); end)
k:bind({}, 'k', function() arrowKey('UP', {}); end, nil, function() arrowKey('UP', {}); end)
k:bind({}, 'l', function() arrowKey('RIGHT', {}); end, nil, function() arrowKey('RIGHT', {}); end)
```

So `HYPER-H` outputs the left arrow key basically. But my issue is that I also want `HYPER-COMMAND-H` to output command-left-arrow-key as that brings the cursor to the beginning of the line.

```lua
k:bind({'cmd'}, 'n', function() arrowKey('LEFT', {'cmd'}); end, nil, function() arrowKey('LEFT', {'cmd'}); end)
```

I have it looking like that. However, the issue is that HYPER-COMMAND-H works, but COMMAND-HYPER-H **does not**. If I mess up the order of the modifiers (which normally does not matter) it completely breaks, which is super inconvenient.

How would I make it so that the order doesn't matter? F18 isn't a proper modifier key so I'm having real trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I have [written a script](https://github.com/harsilspatel/dotfiles/blob/master/hammerspoon/hotkeyextension/hotkeyextension.lua) that allows me to attain a similar effect as creating a new hyper key.

I have written a hotkey extension that distinguishes between left and right modifier keys. This means that I can bind the combination of right command (`rcmd`) and s to open Spotify, while the combination of left command and s retains its default behavior (such as the save command in most applications).

To use this extension, save the script `hotkeyextension.hs` in the same directory as `init.hs`, and then include the following line to import it `require 'hotkeyextension'`.

You can then use it as follows:

```lua
hs.hotkeyextension.bind({'rcmd'}, 's', launchOrFocus('Spotify'))
```

The function signature for `hs.hotkeyextension.bind` can be located [here](https://github.com/harsilspatel/dotfiles/blob/master/hammerspoon/hotkeyextension/hotkeyextension.lua#L157-L167).

Comment: The link is broken, the correct link is [this](https://github.com/harsilspatel/dotfiles/blob/master/config/hammerspoon/hotkeyextension/hotkeyextension.lua).